# Random int with no repeat in c++

Tags: random

I am making a quiz application.
All the questions are strored in table and every question means one row. Every row is an int variable.
Program prints 3 random questions from 5 stored questions with this code:

```
i = rand() % 5 + 1;
```

i means a row in table, so it randomly chooses one row and question and print it. It all i labeled as "QUESTION" and in the end there is a code:

```
goto QUESTION;
```

Which makes the program choose the question once again.
What code should I implement more to make the program **NOT TO** choose questions already choosen?

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the first question, store the question number in an array.

For the next question, again apply the same technique of using `rand()` to find the next question. But check if it matches with the value of row already stored in the array. If the question number matches, keep on applying the `rand()` function to get new question number until the question number is different from the first. Once you get the different question, update the array.

Similarly, do it for the third question as well

Hope it helps!!!